# Get DB values from remote server in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to display the table values from remote db.for that I did following in the controller

```
      def show
        @dev = Detail.find(:all)
        #raise @devices.inspect
      end
```

in `show.html.erb`

```
<h1>TrDeviceDetails#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/tr_device_details/show.html.erb</p>
<%= @dev %>
```

The page displayed the table with values.

```
[#<Detail UniqueDeviceID: 14448, SlNo: 609">, #<Detail UniqueDeviceID: 14448, SlNo: 610">].
```

I need to display only the  `SlNo`.when I write `<%=Detail.find(:SlNo)%>` getting error

```
undefined method `to_i' for :SlNo:Symbol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already found all devises in `show` method of the controller. You need to iterate over the all records

```
<% @dev.each do |d| %>
  Dev id: <%= d.SlNo %>
<% end %>
```

Also going by the convention the column names should be in downcase with separation of `_`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you should use each_with_index,it will avoid error occurence.

```
<% @dev.each_with_index do |page, index| %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the query in your show method. Keep it as it is.

However, the above query returns the total records of a detail table in a hash and not just one.

In order to get only the `SlNo`, you need to loop over each record and then get `SlNo` for each.

So in your show html do the following:

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @dev.each do |dev| %>

<%= dev.SlNo %> #displays only the SlNo.

<% end %>
```